Passing value from ACF to Contact Form 7 Dropdown Menu
I have followed a guide on how to do this but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working.
In ACF I have added a checkbox that allows us to choose from two options when adding a new post.
From here, I have added the following into Contact Form 7:
[select my-values data:my_possible_values]

And in my functions.php file I have added the following:
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function($n, $options, $args) {
  if (in_array('my_possible_values', $options)){
    
    // Assuming that my_acf_field is an ACF multi-select field
    $my_possible_values = get_field('the_name_of_my_field');

    // turn $my_possible_values into an array
    // that looks like this: ['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3']
    return array_map(function($el) {
        return $el['value'];
    }, $my_possible_values);
  }
  return $n;
}, 10, 3);

the_name_of_my_field is matches up with the field name I gave the checkbox in ACF.
When I view the contact form I can see a dropdown menu but it doesn't show the values I've selected from ACF.
Is there anything I'm missing? Thank you.
I tried adding code from another post I found that linked to this website: https://bdwm.be/dynamically-populate-a-contact-form-7-dropdown-list-or-any-other-input-field/ - I was expecting a dropdown menu to display with multiple options but it just shows empty.

How are the field values stored, are they already an array?  If they're in a postmeta field, which ACF is, then wouldn't multiple values be stored as a serialized array?
